# MySQL Error 1215 - Foreign key (date type) to Primary key (Date type)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I am trying to reference PostDate from Speech to PostDate from `P_ASSIGNMENT` but it is giving me `"Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint"`.
I am currently working on InnoDB on MySQL Workbench.

Here is my SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE P_ASSIGNMENT
(StaffID int not null,
 JobID int not null,
 PostDate date not null,
 EndDate date,
 CONSTRAINT P_Assignment_pk PRIMARY KEY (StaffID, JobID, PostDate),
);

CREATE TABLE SPEECH
 (EventName varchar(100) not null,
  EventDate date not null,
  OrderNum int not null,
  ContentAbst varchar(250),
  Contact int not null,
  Presenter int not null,
  JobID int not null,
  PostDate date not null,
 CONSTRAINT Speech_pk PRIMARY KEY (EventName, EventDate, OrderNum),
 CONSTRAINT Speech_fk3 FOREIGN KEY (Presenter) REFERENCES P_ASSIGNMENT (StaffID),
 CONSTRAINT Speech_fk4 FOREIGN KEY (JobID) REFERENCES P_ASSIGNMENT (JobID),
 CONSTRAINT Speech_fk5 FOREIGN KEY (PostDate) REFERENCES P_ASSIGNMENT(PostDate)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a **single** composite foreign key. The syntax is:

```
CREATE TABLE SPEECH
 (EventName varchar(100) not null,
  EventDate date not null,
  OrderNum int not null,
  ContentAbst varchar(250),
  Contact int not null,
  Presenter int not null,
  JobID int not null,
  PostDate date not null,
 CONSTRAINT Speech_pk PRIMARY KEY (EventName, EventDate, OrderNum),
 CONSTRAINT Speech_fk3 FOREIGN KEY (Presenter, JobID, PostDate) -- fix here
   REFERENCES P_ASSIGNMENT (StaffID, JobID, PostDate)
);
```

Just to make the point clear, you don't have three foreign keys. You have a single foreign key. That foreign key is a composite key since it includes three columns.